# Common causes of burnt tips on herbs

Tags: herbs, hydroponic

What are common causes of these burnt tips?

Over/under fertilization? Too much/little light? Nutrient deficiency?

This is Korean shiso/perilla growing in a deep water culture. I've also seen it on basil grown in soil.

[image: Burnt tips on shiso]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like nitrogen and potassium deficiency to me.

From [Chapter 4, *Soil fertility and crop production*](ftp://ftp.fao.org/docrep/fao/009/a0443e/a0443e02.pdf) of the book [*Plant Nutrition for Food Security - A guide for integrated nutrient management*](ftp://ftp.fao.org/agl/agll/docs/fpnb16.pdf) published by the [Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations](http://www.fao.org/home/en/):

> ### Deficiencies indicated by symptoms appearing first on older leaves
>
> - chlorosis starting from leaf tips, later leaves turn yellowish-brown: N
> - reddish/purple discoloration on green leaves or stalks: P
> - leaves with brown necrotic margins and/or spots: K
> - stripe chlorosis, mainly between veins, while veins remain green: Mg
> - spot necrosis: greyish-brown stripe-form spots in oats (grey-speck disease): Mn
> - dark-brown spots in oats and barley, whitish spots in rye and wheat: Mn
>
> ### Deficiencies indicated by symptoms appearing first on younger leaves:
>
> - completely yellowish-green leaves with yellowish veins: S
> - yellow or pale yellow to white leaves with green veins: Fe
> - youngest leaf with white, withered and twisted tip: Cu
> - yellowish leaves with brownish spots and/or leaf deformed (part of acidity syndrome): Ca

Comment: Any references for more info? Awesome answer @Randy!